# jQuery .reset function is Not working under particuller button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've two forms on same page and I've following code:

**Working for education form:**

```
$(".add-education").on('click', function (e) {
    $('.education-edit').slideDown();
    $('.education-view').slideUp();
    $("#educ_form").reset();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Working for experience form:**

```
$(".add-experience").on('click', function (e) {
    $('.experience-edit').slideUp();
    $('.experience-view').slideDown();
    $("#exp_form").reset();
});
```

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ersamrow/rLgqom47/)

What I'm missing..? Please help.

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: For both form the code is working? Please describe your question like what part is not working.

Comment: Put the actual problem in your question, not just in the title. For people who barely pay attention to titles, your question has no point to it.

Comment: I've add fiddle,Please have a look

Comment: What button do you click? What happens next? Any error messages?  What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
$("#educ_form").reset();
```

into:

```
$("#educ_form")[0].reset();
```

**Why?**

`.reset()` isn't a jQuery function, and should be executed on the element, rather than the jQuery object. By going to the `[0]` (first array value). You access the `getElementById()` version.

Comment: Its working for educ_form but not woking in add-experience button click

Comment: Add your html please

Comment: Fiddle added @Roberrrt

Comment: #educ_form doesn't exist in your HTML.